# match particular url parameter and return its value

Tags: javascript, regex

I have URL like 
 `https://some-domain/auth/authenticate?auth=1c4cf948-0867-488d-8596&client_id=account&tab_id=0p-SoVza1Sw` 
I want to get the value of `tab_id` by using regex. 
I have done it through JS but I want a regEx to return `0p-SoVza1Sw`. 
I tried this `/tab_id=([^&]+)&*/g` but it matches with `tab` word also

I know it would be easy but am not good at regex, Thank you

Comment: Your value is in capture group 1. You can omit the `&*` if it is optional `tab_id=([^&]+)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a lookbehind assertion here:

```
(?<=[?&]tab_id=)[^&]+
```

### Demo

Comment: Tim, I got you, It worked. Thank you.